# Jasmine throws error on expect().toThrow instead of identifying the thrown error

Tags: javascript, jasmine, tdd, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to implement functions for printing a diamond in terms of learning test driven development in javascript.

```
Diamond.prototype.outerSpace = function (current, widest) {

  var currentValue = this.getIndexOf(current);
  var widestValue = this.getIndexOf(widest);

  if (currentValue > widestValue) {
      throw new Error('Invalid combination of arguments');
  }

  var spaces = widestValue - currentValue;
  return new Array(spaces + 1).join(' ');
};
```

I have problems in Error handling. The function above should throw an error, if currentValue is greater than widestValue.

This is my snippet representing the test/spec:

```
it ("should throw an exception, if it is called with D and C", function () {
    var outerSpace = diamond.outerSpace.bind(diamond, 'D', 'C');
    expect(outerSpace).toThrow('Invalid combination of arguments');
});
```

I've tried also with an anonymous function in expect(..), but this also didn't work.

The Console message is: Expected function to throw 'Inval...' but it throw Error: Invalid combination of arguments.

I don't get it, what I should do with this information.

Edit: It is strange, because it is working with Jasmine v.1.3, but it didnt work  with jasmine v.2.3 i.e. or with karma, although the code based on jasmine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR**

With Jasmine 2 the matchers semantics changed and there's a new matcher.

Use `toThrowError("<message>")` or `toThrow(new Error("<message>")))`

**NTL;TR**

Since Jasmine 2.x there is a new Matcher `toThrowError()` and Jasmine's `toThrow()` got a new semantic.

- `toThrow()` should be used to check if *any error was throw* or to check for the message of an `Error` (more concrete: someting that's `instanceof Error`)
- `toThrowError()` should be used to check if a *specific* error was thrown or if the message of the error equals the expectation

Internally `toThrow(x)` makes an equality check of the thrown error against `x`. If both the error and `x` are `instanceof Error` (which would be true for `TypeError` too for example) Jasmine checks equality (`===` in general) of both sides `message` attributes.

The form `toThrowError(x)` checks whether the error message equals or matches `x` (string or RegExp)

The other form `toThrowError(t, x)` checks whether the error is of type `t` and message equals or matches `x` (string or RegExp)

See

- [Jasmine 2.3 Included Matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers) (Examples at the end of the block)
- [Source of toThrow()](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.3/src/core/matchers/toThrow.js)
- [Source of toThrowError()](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.3/src/core/matchers/toThrowError.js)